# JS: Is optional chaining necessary if only the last field might be null?

Tags: javascript

I am getting an error in NewRelic showing a JS error for ``cannot read property timerShow of null .  I have traced it to this function:

```
isShown() {
    return this.person.value.timerShow === this.timerActive;
}
```

When I go to log `this.person.value`, it is an object but doesn't have `timerShow` as a field on it sometimes.  Wouldn't that still work though and just result in `false` if it doesn't have `timerShow`?

I thought the use of optional chaining was if you were unsure of the value higher up the chain like:

```
isShown() {
    return this.person?.value?.timerShow === this.timerActive;
}
```

where `value` has the potential to be null

Comment: As the error states there is a case when the value of `this.person.value` is `null`. You'll need to debug that

Comment: "*When I go to log `this.person.value`, it is an object*" - apparently not always. If this doesn't match your expectations, find the source of the problem, instead of just fixing it by `this.person.value?.timerShow`. Yes, if only `timerShow` doesn't exist, that simply results in the comparison yielding `false`.

Comment: @Bergi thank you.  Just to be clear though, IF `value` was always guaranteed to be an object, an optional on `timerShow` wouldn't be necessary right?  `this.person.value?.timerShow` would be the same as `this.person.value.timerShow`, right?

Comment: no accessing some method on something which is null throws an error, but if you use `?` then it will just return undefined

Comment: @HarLinton Yes, if `value` always was an object, you could use `value.…` instead of `value?.…`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
isShown() {
    if(typeof this.person?.value?.timerShow == "undefined")
        return false;
    return this.person?.value?.timerShow === this.timerActive;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
isShown() {
    return this.person?.value?.timerShow ?? 'your return here '
}
```

If there is nothing in the first part, it returns the second part of ??